# How to implement nested QComboBox in PyQt6?

Tags: qt, pyqt, nested, qcombobox

Is there a straightforward (without reimplementing too many members, I mean) way to use a QComboBox as QComboBox Item?

The effect I would like to achieve is a plain QComboBox showing a single value when closed, when opened it should display the normal list; some (or all) list items could be nested QComboBox which can be opened to select nested entries in a tree-like logic. When closed the QComboBox should display (and QSignal) just the selected item in the selected sub-combo.

Is this possible (without rewriting the whole widget, of course)?

I am using PyQt6, if relevant.

I am aware of possibility to use a `QTreeView` as `QComboBox` via:

```py
...
wh = QComboBox()
tv = QTreeView()
wh.setView(tv)
wh.setModel(QStandardItemModel())
...
```

This seems much simpler than the pointed "solving answer", but it leads to inconsistent behavior and clipped lists (exactly as solving answer original code; @musicamante comments are completely right).

What I'm aiming at is something different, I have the following (completely unsatisfactory, see below) code:

```py
from PyQt6.QtCore import pyqtSignal, pyqtSlot, Qt
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QPushButton

class RecursiveComboBox(QPushButton):
    clicked = pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.model_data = None
        self.level = parent.level + 1 if parent else 0
        self.w = QWidget()
        self.w.hide()

    def set_my_data(self, model_data: dict):
        self.model_data = model_data
        l = QVBoxLayout()
        for k, v in self.model_data.items():
            if isinstance(v, dict):
                i = RecursiveComboBox(self)
                i.setText(k)
                i.clicked.connect(self.node_clicked)
                print(f'{"  "*self.level}[{self.level} -- {self.text()}]: node_clicked conected')
                i.set_my_data(v)
            else:
                i = QPushButton(text=k, parent=self)
                i.setProperty('user_data', v)
                i.clicked.connect(self.leaf_clicked)
                print(f'{"  " * self.level}[{self.level} -- {self.text()}]: leaf_clicked conected')
            l.addWidget(i)
        self.w.setLayout(l)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.MouseButton.LeftButton and self.rect().contains(event.pos()):
            self.setEnabled(False) # release is implicit
            self.repaint()
            self.w.show()
        else:
            super().mouseReleaseEvent(event)

    @pyqtSlot(str)
    def node_clicked(self, txt):
        print(f'node_clicked({txt}): [{self.level} -- {self.text()}]')
        self.clicked.emit(txt)
        self.w.hide()
        self.setEnabled(True)

    @pyqtSlot(bool)
    def leaf_clicked(self, _):
        child = self.sender()
        print(f'leaf_clicked({child.text()}): [{self.level} -- {self.text()}]')
        self.clicked.emit(child.text())
        self.w.hide()
        self.setEnabled(True)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QVBoxLayout

    main_course = {
        'meat': {
            'steak': 'steak',
            'meatballs': 'meatballs',
        },
        'fish': {
            'cod': 'cod',
            'mullet': 'mullet',
            'scallops': 'scallops'
        },
        'vegetarian': {
            'salad': {
                'mixed': 'mixed',
                'cesar': 'cesar'
            },
            'flan': 'flan'
        }
    }

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    mw = QWidget()
    lo = QVBoxLayout()
    rc = RecursiveComboBox()
    rc.setText('Main course')
    lo.addWidget(rc)
    mw.setLayout(lo)
    rc.set_my_data(main_course)

    rc.clicked.connect(lambda s: print(f'click event for "{s}"'))

    mw.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

This code has the correct (for me) behavior:

- it shows a single "button"
- it if "button" is clicked it opens a list of sub-buttons
- this behavior is recursive recursive
- when clicking on a "leaf" button the whole hierarchy is closed and the single leaf is returned via `pyqtSignal`

OTOH this code has several issues I need help with: essentially it doesn't look like a combobox at all.

It opens unrelated windows for each nested list; this is because I don't set a parent in the constructor: `self.w = QWidget()` should be `self.w = QWidget(self)`, but that leads to a clipped visualization.

There are other minor issues I think I can handle (or open separate questions for them), but the main issue is: How do I `self.w.show()` in the same place as `self` resizing it according to contents?

Comment: I don't see it very feasible, nor user friendly. Maybe a combobox is not what you should use, as what you're describing seems more like a simple menu with submenus.

Comment: @musicamante: actually it seems I can `QComboBox.setView(QTreeView())' which might be what I need... if I manage to understand how to harness the beast.

Comment: I thought you already considered and excluded that. Note that while it's completely possible to use a QTreeView as popup for combo boxes, it has its own drawbacks. For instance, expansion and collapse of item can make items less visible, and the popup may not be big enough to properly show the whole structure (or too big while not required). I still believe that a popup menu with submenus might be a better choice. If you use QToolButton you can also get a behavior that is "similar" to that of QComboBox (showing the "current selection") by using `setDefaultAction()` when an item is selected.

Comment: @musicamante: Thanks. I came up with a solution, but I would really like to have your expert review as I am on a steep learning curve on Qt/PyQt and I'm unsure if all that stuff is really needed. One thing I actually do *not* like in my solution is it's fully possibl to select "non leaf" items, but I don't know how to prevent it.

Comment: If you want to prevent selection of parent items, then override the `flags()` of the model, get the default ones and eventually remove the `Qt.ItemIsSelectable` enum if the item `hasChildren()`. `def flags(self, index):` `flags = super().flags(index)` `if self.hasChildren(index):` `flags &= ~Qt.ItemFlag.ItemIsSelectable` `return flags`. Note that this won't completely solve your problems, and that's one of the reasons for which using a tree view for a combo may create more problems than it'd solve: for example, if you use the wheel on the combo, you'll only be able to select top level items.

Comment: @musicamante: Thanks. I'll try to follow advice for `flags()` override and I will update my own answe accordingly; OTOH I am in the dark about how to implement your other suggestion (menu/submenu), if you car to shape an Answer with a tiny example... ;)

Comment: Is the model actually required? Or was it necessary only because of the combo? And, if the model *is* required, is it static (loaded on startup) or can it change the structure at runtime?

Comment: @musicamante: should we move to chat(if you have time, of course)? To make a long story short: I have a model because I load a lot of data from disk; I use the same model for many different views, selecting different parts. Back to the ComboBoxes: I need several of them each displaying a selection of a large collection (total number is ~2000) each "subsection" is limited, but not tiny (20..100 items) and a few ComboBoxes should display a few (max 3) subsections. I *can* refill combo/tree/menu each time, but I thought using `QSortFilterProxyModel` would be better.

Comment: I opened a direct chat (you should receive a notification), as I don't remember if moving the discussion to the chat will also migrate comments.